# How to create as many HTML div tag as Columns of a GridView?

Tags: c#, html

I have a gridview with many columns. I was wondering how could I create as many `<div>` tags as there is data in the gridView.

The gridView data comes from a sql database.

I want to show the data that corresponds to the product's comments. It's almost like a Comment Area that many webpages have.

Comment: Where do you want to place those divs? Will they be in each column or outside the GridView?

Comment: in the source code of my asp webpage, I want to know if i can create those divs with a for bucle iterating each field data and creating tags with that data.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, where?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change all your `BoundField` to `TemplateField`

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvProducts">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateFied HeaderText="ProductName">
       <div><%# Eval("ProductName")</div>

       <div class="CommentArea"> Some text here </div>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateFied HeaderText="Column2">
       <div><%# Eval("Column2Data")</div>

       <div class="CommentArea"> Some text here </div>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateFied HeaderText="Column3">
       <div><%# Eval("Column3Data")</div>

       <div class="CommentArea"> Some text here </div>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   ...

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```